# How to pass in parameters for in clause that is in a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How would I take this query that is in my stored procedure and pass in the correct parameters?

```
select * from Inventory
where category in (@categories) and qty > @qty and condition in (@conditions)
```

I seen that I should do something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DoSomethingWithTableTypedParameter]
(
    @categories categories READONLY
    @Qty int,
    @conditions
)
```

But how does the ADO.NET side look like? If I were to pass in for categories  'Tools', 'Hardware' and for conditions 'New', 'Used'.

How would I do this?

Comment: And don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Do you have documentation for this, @DaleK ? Everything I've ever seen specifically on Table Value Parameters, including the the [documention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing), uses `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK , that's really useful :)

Comment: Also, pretty sure that last link if a good duplicate candidate for this question. :)

Comment: yes qty would be a single value coming in and the rest of the conditions are in clauses. In my real query I probably will have a couple single value parameters coming in at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add 3 further parameters to your SP, `@Qty`, `@Category` & `@Condition` you just duplicate the steps you've already taken.

1. Create any additional User Defined Table Types

Both `@Category` and `@Condition` need a UDT, `@Qty` doesn't as it is a native type.

Some people will prefer having a separate UDT each for `@Category` and `@Condition`, personally given they both take the same datatype I create a single general purpose utility UDT e.g.

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_ShortString] AS TABLE
(
    [Value] [varchar](128) NULL
)
```

2. Modify the SP e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_DoSomethingWithTableTypedParameter]
(
    @UserIdList udt_UserId READONLY
    , @CategoryList udt_ShortString READONLY
    , @ConditionList udt_ShortString READONLY
    , @Qty int
)
AS
```

3. Add the values to your `command` object, where you load the new datatables exactly the same as you are already loading your existing userId table e.g.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserIdList", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured) { TypeName = "udt_UserId", Value = userIdList });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CategoryList", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured) { TypeName = "udt_ShortString", Value = categoryList });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ConditionList", System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured) { TypeName = "udt_ShortString", Value = conditionList });
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = qty });
```

Note: For clarity I have hardcoded the parameter names and type names in - you are of course free to pass them as variabled as you were doing.

Comment: So, I will have to duplicate all the data for each "row" (maybe roleId, was a bad example as each user could have a different role). If I say had something like CreatedDate what I wanted to do a between range or if I had another "in" clause how would it be added to the row?

Comment: Ok, let me come up with an example.

Comment: ok, so I am not creating a separate Table scrip in the database? Also how and what am I populating in the data table?

Comment: I mean do I need to make something like? CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_UserId] AS TABLE

Comment: so would I make 3 parameters one for qty, one for category, one for condition?

Comment: Ah then I misunderstood what you were asking, all values in the where condition are coming in from the C# code.

Comment: Yes, it is starting to make more sense, I basically have to create a UDT for each parameter. That was what was tripping me up. As I thought I would have to make all the parameters. To be clear you are not using Datatables and dataRows correct? This was something else I thought you had to do as well.

Comment: You have to create a UDT for each distinct parameter type - I have a handful of common data combinations which I use.

Comment: Yes it still needs a datatable per UDT parameter, exactly as you are already loading the values into your userID parameter in C#. So you need 3 datatables now.

Comment: Ok, when I make the datatable what do I put for the data column?  I am not sure what it is being used for since you are using SqlParamater (I think maybe data column has a bigger use if you use AddWithValue)

Comment: Also is there a downside to use varchar(Max) otherwise I going to have to make a few of these just for different type sizes.

Comment: @chobo2 Your original datatable used `dt.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(int));` for an int, so for a string you would use `dt.Columns.Add("UserId", typeof(string));` (There are .net/sql datatype conversions which you can google). There is no downside to using `varchar(max)` as you say its more versitle.

Comment: well what does the "column name" from the data table get used for if we are passing in a parameter?

Comment: @chobo2 At this point you're asking why does the sun shine :) the answer is Microsoft designed it that way. Under the hood the .NET framework has to convert the datatable you provide into an SQL data structure. I don't know how the internals work. I just know how you make use of it. Name the columns in your datatable the same as in your UDT and match the datatypes and it will work :)

Comment: I believe so - thats what works anyway. Its entirely possible it ignores the column name and just works on position - but I always name them consistently.